What’s the best way to achieve real-time collaborative editing in Neovim?
I've been trying to set up a real-time collaborative editing environment in Neovim, similar to VS Code’s Live Share feature. Is there a way to share a buffer and allow multiple users to edit it simultaneously within Neovim? Any plugin recommendations or configurations would be appreciated.
I initially tried using the instant.nvim plugin, which works well for local collaborative editing (within the same LAN), but doesn't support remote collaboration over the internet. I also attempted to use Neovim's built-in remote functionality in combination with ngrok to expose the server, but configuring everything was cumbersome and not very practical for everyday use.

Here you can find a great resource with plugins for Neovim that might catch your interest:
https://neovimcraft.com/?search=tag%3Aremote-development
In particular, this plugin seems to do exactly what you need:
https://neovimcraft.com/plugin/azratul/live-share.nvim
